# Symfony kernel creates 302-redirect instead of using correct route

Tags: symfony, routes

I am building a Symfony 5.3 app and have mapped the route `/logout` to a controller method `logout()`.

Running the symfony console with `router:match /logout` yields for the value of "Defaults": `App\Controller\IndexController::logout()`, just as expected.

But when I visit the page in my browser with xdebug enabled and breakpoints put at multiple relevant points in my code, I see that even though the route is correctly matched (the log agrees), the logout method in the controller is never run. A simple `$logger->debug("This is never run")` confirms that it's not just a xdebug issue.

Instead, the kernel decides to return a 302 that redirects to "/" without even touching the method.

I have checked that my browser doesn't cache old redirects and have run `cache:clear` in the console a few times.

What could possibly cause this behaviour? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony never actually calls your controller for logout, it executes its own logic and redirects user to some page. If you need to customize logout behaviour please hook into the `LogoutEvent` event as per documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#customizing-logout

Comment: That was valuable information! So does that mean that either "/logout" and/or the route name "app_logout" are already defined by Symfony and thus the default logic applies? I had registered this method as the default handler for the logout as described above the paragraph you linked to, using path: app_logout

Comment: But yes, I can now see that it says in the example logout method "// controller can be blank: it will never be executed!" I had missed that. Thanks!